# CSVHelper, go back to the beginning after reading the header row

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I have the following code where I look at columns headers before some condition statement:

```
var csvConfig = new CsvHelper.Configuration.CsvConfiguration(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)
                {
                    // csvconfig.Delimiter = "\t";
                    HasHeaderRecord = true
                };    

using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
using (CsvReader csv1 = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
{ 
    
                        CsvReader csv2 = csv1;
                        csv2.Read();
                        csv2.ReadHeader();
    
                        string[] headers = csv2.HeaderRecord;
    if(headers[0].Replace("\0", "").ToUpper() == "TEST")
    {
              using (var dr1 = new CsvDataReader(csv1))
              {
                  var dt1 = new DataTable();
                  dt1.Load(dr1);
              }
    }
}
```

I thought that by having 2 variables for the CsvReader (csv1 and csv2) it would be feasible but it seems that they both use the same object in memory.
Therefore when I want to use csv2 to fill my datatable, the header row has been already read in csv1 and is not loaded in my datatable.

How can I make sure that csv2 contains the whole csv and is distinct from csv1? Is there a method to go back to the beginning or do I need to read the whole CSV again using CsvReader?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

In C#, datas types are categorized based on how they store their value in the memory : by value or by reference (by pointer exists too).

For example, a string is usually stored by value but complex objects like your reader are almost always stored by reference.

When you do `csv2 = csv1` both now refer to the same memory area. This means that they are 2 names for the same thing. When you do an action on csv1, csv2 also receives it since they are 2 aliases for the same information.

Try if CSVreader implements Clone() :

```
 CsvReader csv2 = csv1.Clone();
```

If it is, the function will create a **new** object with the same informations which do not share the same memory area.

Comment: Unfortunately, `CsvReader` does not implement `Clone()`.  In most cases it wouldn't make sense to clone `CsvReader`, since the two clones would be sharing the same data stream and the manipulation of the stream by one clone would affect the data stream of the other one.

Answer (score 0):

You need a separate `CsvReader` for `csv1` and `csv2`. As both you @UserNam3 advise, you don't want `csv2` to be referencing the same object as `csv1` in memory.  They will both be using the same `Stream`, so after reading the header with `csv2` you will need to reset the `Stream` back to the beginning.

```cs
using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))
using (CsvReader csv1 = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
using (CsvReader csv2 = new CsvReader(reader, csvConfig))
{
    csv2.Read();
    csv2.ReadHeader();

    string[] headers = csv2.HeaderRecord;
    
    reader.BaseStream.Position = 0;

    if(headers[0].Replace("\0", "").ToUpper() == "TEST")
    {
        using (var dr1 = new CsvDataReader(csv1))
        {
            var dt1 = new DataTable();
            dt1.Load(dr1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, it was my first thought to create 2 distincts CsvReader but it seemed couterproductive and memory consuming while having a property on my first CsvREader to go backwards at the beginning of the csv would have been more straightforward. I don't know if such a property exists in this library.

Comment: I just tried you code and it seems that there is something wrong. csv2 return 9 columns while dt1 contains only 4 columns. There must be some issues with some referenced memory.

Comment: Ok to make it work, I have to add an other `using (StreamReader reader2 = new StreamReader(filePath, Encoding.UTF8))` . It looks like the redaer is using the same object in memory too.